# How to run a function when nodeapp returns error

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to be able throw a function when my node app returns error

Let's say I have a simple node app

```
var express= require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('hello')
})

app.listen(2500);
```

if there is an error while running the app, it might be related to the port or i might not have a proper node package module installed i just want it to run a function.. how do i do that?

I want it to `console.log('node crashed')` for example

Comment: What do you mean by "throw a function"? Errors are thrown...as the docs say (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html), "Any use of the JavaScript throw mechanism will raise an exception that must be handled using try / catch or the Node.js process will exit immediately". If an error is thrown, then it will output the error to the console before exiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for `uncaughtException` event:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', err => console.log('Error:', err));
```

but you should really handle the errors where they appear, so e.g. you should handle the port binding error explicitly:

```
var server = app.listen(2500);
server.on('error', err => console.log('Listen error:', err.message));
```

and handle other errors in the same fashion. Otherwise you will not be able to do anything to actually recover from the error, other than saying: oops.